# Lombok's annotations in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lombok

I have trouble with using Lombok's annotations, cause it seems like jar wasn't even imported to project:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

/**
 * Created by John on 2017-03-20.
 */
@Slf4j
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        log.info("Hello");
    }
}
```

It says:

> Cannot resolve method info(java.lang.String)

When compiling:

> Error:(6, 1) java: package org.slf4j does not exist

I did:

1. Insert lombok's dependency into pom
2. Installed lombok plugin for Intellij
3. Enabled annotations processing
4. Imported dependencies to project (they are on external libs list)

I've looked for a solution here:

- [Lombok added but getters and setters not recognized in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729384/lombok-added-but-getters-and-setters-not-recognized-in-intellijidea)
- [Can't compile project when I'm using Lombok under IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424364/cant-compile-project-when-im-using-lombok-under-intellij-idea)
- [Building with Lombok's @Slf4j and Intellij: Cannot find symbol log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866765/building-with-lomboks-slf4j-and-intellij-cannot-find-symbol-log)

Still the same problem. Any advice would be appriciated.

UPDATE:
pom.xml if it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Looks like you did all correctly, try to check one more time [according to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea)

Comment: Have you actually added the slf4j dependency?

Comment: @LevKuznetsov Slf4j is in Lombok dependency: https://projectlombok.org/features/Log.html

Comment: I don't see Lombok depending on anything in the link you provided.

Comment: @LevKuznetsov Lombok IntelliJ plugin recognizes annotations and adds libs to project: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You also need to add at least the slf4j-api dependency to your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

1. Add lombok to your dependency, and make sure the package is downloaded properly.
2. Install the lombok plugin for Intellij.
3. Enable annotation processing in Intellij: Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> Enable Annotation processing.
4. Restart Intellij.

Comment: I have IDEA Intellij 16.3.5 on Ubuntu so I have File->Settings instead of Preferences. I don't know if it changes anything. I did everything you've listed. It's in my post.