# Lombok IntelliJ integration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, lombok, artifact

I'm having trouble building my project in IntelliJ using Lombok. Lombok appears to work fine until I go to build artifact, where I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ24G.png) error any place that uses a Lombok getter.

However, the code that shows up error free here [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0hcj.png):

I have annotation processing enabled, and lombok is a dependency. I can't seem to figure out why this is,

Comment: What are you using to build the artifact?  Is *it* aware of Lombok?

Comment: Build -> Build Artifacts. Should be, I have it listed [here](http://i.imgur.com/D88e4TU.png).

Comment: have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729384/lombok-added-but-getters-and-setters-not-recognized-in-intellij-idea?rq=1  ?

Comment: Yep :/ I've already done everything listed there.

Comment: Oh haha. Figured it out. I was using an old version of Lombok from when I setup everything in Eclipse. After I updated it to the latest version it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should install Lombok Intellij Plugin to be able to build your project:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `OSX/ Mac`, enable annotation processing (tick the checkbox) at these two places (Not sure about windows or any other platform).

> 1.) Intellij IDEA => Preferences => Compiler => Annotation Processors
>
> 2.) File => Other Settings => Default Settings => Compiler => Annotation Processors

And then

> 3.) Intellij IDEA => Preferences => Plugins => Browse Repositories => Search for "Lombok" => install plugin => Apply
>
> 4.) And then probably restart Intellij IDEA. (This goes without saying :) )

This is my IntelliJ IDEA and Mac Version - IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5 Build #IU-171.4694.70   --- Mac OS X 10.12