# Lombok - access to getter not visible

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I used lombok annotation '@Data' in my entity. I was trying to use getter by Dto Converter in the same way like I would do it normally without lombok. Somehow it doesn't work as I expected. It looks like my lombok didn't create getters or I don't have access there?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

Dto Converter:

```
public class ProductEntityToProductDetailsDtoConverterImpl {

    @Override
    public ProductDetailsDto convert(Product product) {
        return new ProductDetailsDto(
                product.getId(),
                product.getName()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: Intellij Idea UE

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA you have to enable it in Settings and before install the Lombok plugin.

Comment: If you use IntelliJ IDEA, you may need to [enable Lombok annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729384/lombok-added-but-getters-and-setters-not-recognized-in-intellij-idea/48470371)

Comment: As a note, while it's convenient to use `@Data`, Entity objects generally should not override `equals` and `hashCode`; it's better to use `@Getter @Setter` (and maybe `@ToString`) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install lombok plugin for your IntellIJ IDEA to make it understand lombok

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok

Comment: It is already answered. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729384/lombok-added-but-getters-and-setters-not-recognized-in-intellij-idea