# Lombok plugin fails to generate getter methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, lombok

```
IDE：IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Play：1.4.4
Lombok：1.18.18
Exception：play.exceptions.CompilationException: The method getId() is undefined for the type Order
        at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:522)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:300)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:420)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAssignableClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:466)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplateCompiler.endTag(GroovyTemplateCompiler.java:362)
        at play.templates.TemplateCompiler.generate(TemplateCompiler.java:93)
        at play.templates.TemplateCompiler.compile(TemplateCompiler.java:15)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplateCompiler.compile(GroovyTemplateCompiler.java:39)
        at play.templates.TemplateCompiler.compile(TemplateCompiler.java:28)
        at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:85)
        at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:180)
        at play.server.PlayHandler.serve500(PlayHandler.java:836)
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

I already checked the settings here, but that didn't fix the problem:
[image: Java Compiler Setting]
[image: Annotation Processors Setting]
[image: Intellij Plugins]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lombok added but getters and setters not recognized in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729384/lombok-added-but-getters-and-setters-not-recognized-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Did you actually add Lombok to the (compile time) classpath of your application?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work on a gradle project (Intellij 2020.3.2)
by using exactly this in build.gradle :

```
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

I think important point is to declare it as "annotationProcessor" type and not "compile" or so.

Answer (score 0):

if someone gets the same issues, I found the answer

just keep the IntelliJ setting all the right

then I trying to change the Lombok version

```
Playframework - 1.4.4
Lombok - 1.18.2
IntelliJ - 2020.3
IntelliJ Plugins - Lombok 0.32-EAP
```

that's work ...