# View lombok generated code in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have the lombok plugin setup in IntelliJ and my code builds fine. I can see the lombok generated methods in the structure view. What I want is some way to actually see the source lombok generates for each of the methods. I realize I can delombok the file but I'm wondering if there is some way I can flip a switch to show or hide the lombok generated code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980133/intellij-idea-cannot-see-lombok-generated-code

Comment: Take a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29982184/636904

Comment: Not sure how that addresses the question. I was hoping to see the generated source inline in the source file.

Comment: did you find anything as of now?

Answer (score 115):

With the Lombok plugin (starting with v0.8.6), "Lombok" and "Delombok" menu items are available in the "Refactor" menu.

[image: IDEA screenshot showing the Lombok & Delombok menu items]

Comment: thanks jjd. what would be very helpful to know is that would re-Lomboking using the above plugin options, just revert the class to what it was...cause the Lomboking options all start with Default...I dont want to change the class from a bespoke Lombok to a default lombok...sorry I am a lombok newbie.

Comment: Just look at the expanded menu right under the one shown, i.e. `Delombok`. That's what you're looking for.

Comment: Does not answer the question

Answer (score 22):

Find generated class in folder target/././classname.class and open it in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: From Review: The question is about a solution for seeing the lombok generated code inline in the original source file in that project.

Comment: Actually this is what I'm looking for. @Vasily Pudikov, you got my up vote. :)

Answer (score 15):

Lombok comes with a '[delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html)' feature that can be used as follows:

```
java -jar lombok.jar delombok -p MyJavaFile.java
```

Comment: Very aware of that as mentioned in the question. I'm looking for something in the IDE where I can flip a toggle or something and see the lombok generated code inline in the original source file in my project.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who arrived here looking for a "delombok" shortcut, one can be created here:

[image]