# Lombok creates multiple setters

Tags: java, lombok

I am new to lombok. I just annotated the pojo with @Data annotation, and it has generated multiple methods. 
do you have an idea what on what can be the reason?

Here is the code,

```
package com.stack.model;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Animal {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

}
```

And, I am getting multiple errors. The default constructor is never generated, and ambiguous methods.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In general case, lombok should not generate "ambiguous" stuff with @Data annotation.
Could you please add a source code of your file?

If you want to see the code generated by lombok, there is something called "delombok" that has been designed just for this purpose. There is also an intelliJ plugin that supports lombok/delombok
Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526286/view-lombok-generated-code-in-intellij-idea) to the question just about this with a very deailed answer about delombok and intelliJ integration

Comment: thank you for your reply, I will check those. I have added the code, not sure if that is enough. Just a simple pojo. I assume this is some config issue.