# capture of ? using Lombok builder

Tags: java, builder, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have this class

```
public class Hostel extends Hotel<Book> {
}
```

and this other one

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "id" })
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class Hotel<T>  {
...
}
```

but when I do

```
Hostel hostel = Hostel.builder().build();
```

I got this compilation error

```
 Required type: Hostel
Provided:
capture of ?
```

Comment: Try annotating the `Hostel` class with a builder. If you want to see the output from lombok, read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526286/view-lombok-generated-code-in-intellij-idea). It will help you figure out the issue.

Comment: You must add `@SuperBuilder` annotation on child classes too ... check here [lombok docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any annotations on Hostel. `Hostel.builder()` is *really* a masquerading `Hotel.builder()`.

So the assignment would have to be

```
final Hotel<?> build = Hostel.builder().build();
```

Or more accurately (making static methods subject to inheritance was IMO a mistake)

```
final Hotel<?> build = Hotel.builder().build();
```

You probably want to add some Lombok annotations to the child class.