# IntelliJ - Switch between Lombok generated code and Lombok annotated code

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I want to [view the Lombok-generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526286/view-lombok-generated-code-in-intellij-idea) code on IntelliJ.

I can see the Lombok/Delombok options. But after refactoring my code, the Lombok options go missing. How can I switch between Lombok generated code and Lombok annotated code multiple times on IntelliJ?

[image]

As shown here, after selecting Refactor -> Lombok options, on those classes, I am unable to see the Lombok option again.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will show up if you put the cursor inside the class and right-click.

[image]