# IntelliJ highlights Lombok generated methods as “cannot resolve method”

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

I am using Lombok’s `@Data` annotation to create the basic functionality of my POJOs. When I try to use these generated methods, IntelliJ highlights these as errors (`Cannot resolve method ‘getFoo()’`) and seems to be unable to find them. They do however exist, as I am able to run code using these methods without any trouble.

I made sure to enable annotation processing, so that shouldn’t cause any problems.

How can I get IntelliJ to find the methods and stop wrongly marking them as errors?

Comment: try refeshing the project ,also check if you can added lombok dependency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't compile project when I'm using Lombok under IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424364/cant-compile-project-when-im-using-lombok-under-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You will also need the [lombok](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317) plugin.

Answer (score 12):

Check if you have added lombok dependency
Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.18</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
provided group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.18'
```

Install Lombok plugin

Preferences > Plugins > Browse Repositories >

Search for "Lombok" and install the plugin

Then you can import

```
import lombok.Data;
```