# IntelliJ Idea doesn't recognize Lombok's annotations

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I'm trying to introduce Lombok annotations into a Maven Java project in IntelliJ IDEA and followed the steps [here](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij) and [here](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven).

@Data annotation (for one) is not being recognized:

[image]

[image]

Here's the relevant Maven stanza:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm on Idea 2017.3.2 CE.

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424364/cant-compile-project-when-im-using-lombok-under-intellij-idea), it doesn't work:

[image]

Doing File | Invalidate Caches & Restart didn't help.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** This question is NOT a duplicate.  I did do all the necessary research prior to posting it.  Don't believe those claiming otherwise.