# Lombok @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = {@MyAnnotation}) compilation error with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have following set up on my mac:

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate: 2018.1
- Lombok Plugin Version: 0.18-2018.1
- Java: 1.8.0_111

Also, I've enabled Annotation Processors as it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30162758/1589723)

But I still have following compilation error:

> Cannot resolve method 'onConstructor_'

Please suggest which configurations are missing.

Comment: Can I ask you something? Do you use any language pack for IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `onConstructor` parameter like this:

```
onConstructor=@__({@AnnotationsHere})
```

See Lombok [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor):

> To put annotations on the generated constructor, you can use onConstructor=@__({@AnnotationsHere})

Comment: Thanks for reply. It looks like that proposed approach related to java 7. I've found following in documentation: https://projectlombok.org/api/index.html?lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor.html. Actually, new styling should be used starting from JDK8.

Comment: proposed parameter works fine, thank you, in any way I am still confused :), since legacy code base using styling mentioned in original question. I am not sure whether this problem on my side or it is some open issue in lombok plugin.

Comment: I suppose it's a mistype in their java-doc. On their site documentation there is only one option. (Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it was helpful...)

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure you have enabled annotation processing and added the lombok plugin in IntelliJ IDEA. This should solve the issue in most of the cases. 
Below is mentioned in the documentation.

```
 * up to JDK7:<br>
     *  {@code @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__({@AnnotationsGoHere}))}<br>
     * from JDK8:<br>
     *  {@code @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_={@AnnotationsGohere})} // note the underscore after {@code onConstructor}.
```