# gradle build fails from terminal for lombok annotation in spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, lombok

I am trying to generate war of spring boot application and using lombok for getter setter. Running gradle build command from terminal and getting error in all getter setter and constructors ie. can not find symbol. I am using STS and able run project successfully from sts. but from command line it throws 100s of errors. I have lombok dependency in gradle file.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14582541/3595026) helped me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 8):

It seems you need to set preprocessor for annotations in your build.gradle file. In STS or IntelliJ, the IDEs provide preprocessing for annotations. However when you want to build via command, you need to specify it in the build.gradle config.

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
}
```

Hope it helps! Happy Coding. :)

Comment: I have already added above  two things in build.gradle still it is same.

Comment: I used gradle lombok plugin after that error are gone for getter and setter but now giving some new message Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags

Comment: It might be caused by the version conflict of lombok and JDK. Which version of JDK do you use?

Comment: jdk10 and lombok1.16.22