# IntelliJ IDEA compile Error in the IDE but can execute the Test

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have this couple of classes in my projects

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class HotelDataForUpdate extends HotelDataForCreateOrUpdate {

    private String id;
    private String lastUpdatedPerid;

}
```

and

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class HotelDataForCreateOrUpdate {

..
}
```

and this line of code in the Junit Test

```
HotelDataForUpdate hotelDataForUpdate = HotelDataForUpdate.builder();
```

that give me the error `Cannot resolve method   builder()` even I rebuild the project 100 times, nevertheless when I push the green arrow to run the test or I do it throw the terminal using `mvn test` I don't have any compilation error and the test runs properly

[image]

I have the lombok plugin enabled and the Enable annotation processing:

[image]

[image]

I am using:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.7479.19, built on May 28, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b58 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424364/cant-compile-project-when-im-using-lombok-under-intellij-idea Also do you have the lombok plugin enabled ?

Comment: Have you invalidated the cache? File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).