# Intellij does not see usage of Lombok getter in implementation class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, overriding, lombok

Can not make Intellij IDEA(v 2021.2.3) navigate to interface method usage from a field inside implementation class with a @Getter of Lombok.
Have the following code structure:

```
public interface Service<ObjectType> {
    SomeQueueClient<ObjectType> getQueueClient();
    int getWorkerCount();
}

@Getter //Same result for @Getter(onMethod = @__(@Override))
public class ServiceImpl implements Service<ExactObjectType> {

    private final SomeQueueClient<ExactObjectType> queueClient;
    private final int workerCount;
}
```

ServiceImpl class is compiled as following without @Override annotation:

```
public class ServiceImpl implements Service<ExactObjectType> {
    
        public SomeQueueClient<ExactObjectType> getQueueClient() {return this.queueClient;}
        public int getWorkerCount() {return this.workerCount;}
    }
```

Code is hard to maintain as you cann't navigate to getter usage of the interface from implementation class(when you click on the field). Lombok plugin bundled. Annotation processing enabled. Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424364/cant-compile-project-when-im-using-lombok-under-intellij-idea

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the issue for this case:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-281219