# Using Lombok in IntelliJ shows create constructor message

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-plugin, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have added Lombok annotation(`@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`) for my following object:

```java
package com.example.demo.student;

import lombok.*;

@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Gender gender;
}
```

The code can be compiled and the application can be run without any issue.

However, the IntelliJ still shows warning red lines about creating constructor like the following screenshot.

Can't IntelliJ recognize Lombok annotations?

Is there any way to stop IntelliJ showing such warning messages?

My IDE version is **IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)**

[image]

Comment: See for Lombok plugin for intellij

Comment: You need the lombok plugin so that IDEA recognizes that the annotations will result in generated code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't compile project when I'm using Lombok under IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424364/cant-compile-project-when-im-using-lombok-under-intellij-idea)

Comment: @magicmn I think my question is much simpler than that. And actually I just solved it by installing the plugin as suggested. Thank you all!  =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it after installed the Lombok plugin for my IntelliJ.

Here is how I did:

1. Go to **File** > **Settings** > **Plugins** .
2. Then search "Lombok" and install the plugin.
3. Restart the IntelliJ and the warning message disappeared.

Thanks for @Barracuda and @f1sh propmpt answer !!